# Get specific data from 2 date for a timerange

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

The data is stored in DB in UTC , I have to convert local to UTC fetch it then show result in local time . 
Now I am from India so if I want to search the data for today I have to query from 22nd March 6:30 PM UTC to 23rd March 6:30 PM UTC . Now Say I want to check   data for every day of week  until now which is 4:30 PM local   . Now I wrote this query [ In simple words my objective is to get visitor number of each day from 12 AM to 4:30 PM ]

```
SELECT
            FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, "2017-03-16 18:29:59",
            visit.date_created)/24) as dayofweek,
            DAYOFWEEK(visit.date_created) day_num,
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 as date_created_set_av,
            count(distinct(visit.pkey)) AS Visits,
            sum(revenue) AS Revenue,
            sum(revenue) / count(distinct(visit.pkey)) as EPC
            FROM la_20.visit, la_20.action 
            cross join (select @rownum := 0) r   
            WHERE visit.pkey=action.pkey  and (visit.is_bot = 0)
            AND visit.date_created >="2017-03-16 18:29:59" 
            AND visit.date_created <="2017-03-23 18:29:59"  
            AND TIME(visit.date_created)<="16:30:00"
   GROUP BY dayofweek order by day_num
```

but what it does is fetch the value from 2017-03-23 00:00:00 to 2017-03-23 16:30:00 . What I need is to show result of 16th to 23rd everyday's data from 18:29:59 to 16:30:00. Remember I need the result of everyday's not one day's. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following where clause instead?

```
WHERE visit.pkey=action.pkey and (visit.is_bot = 0)
        AND visit.date_created >="2017-03-22 18:29:59" 
        AND visit.date_created <="2017-03-23 14:29:59"
```

**3. Edit**
OK, since OP wants something different again - and why not ;-) - here is another  solution that might (or might not) solve his problem:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -7 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -7 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm7,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -6 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -6 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm6,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -5 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -5 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm5,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -4 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -4 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm4,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -3 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -3 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm3,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -2 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -2 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm2,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
        adddate(curdate(), interval -1 day) AND addtime(adddate(curdate(), interval -1 day),'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) dm1,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN d between 
                curdate()                   AND addtime(        curdate()                  ,'16:00:00')
             THEN 1 END ) today
FROM (select     '2017-03-17 15:00:01' d
union all select '2017-03-19 14:00:01'
union all select '2017-03-19 12:00:01'
union all select '2017-03-19 13:00:01'
union all select '2017-03-19 11:00:01'
union all select '2017-03-20 11:20:01'
union all select '2017-03-20 11:30:01'
union all select '2017-03-20 10:40:01'
union all select '2017-03-20 10:23:01' ) dates
```

This is an isolated query that works directly on the sample data given in the subquery. It results in the following list ("dm1"=day minus 1):

```
dm7 | dm6 | dm5 | dm4 | dm3 | dm2 | dm1 | today
  1 |   0 |   4 |   4 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     0
```

You can test it here: http://rextester.com/ITLBL24540

Comment: I edited my question a little bit , what I want is on a specific instance like at 4:00 PM my local time I want to check everyday's data so 12:00 midnight to 4:00 PM noon I want to see everyday's data . Right now what it does is it shows today's data till 4:00 but for others it shows whole day's data .

Comment: My question might not be clear  1) I am trying to retrieve 7 days result 2) I want to show data from 12 midnight to 4 PM everyday's data  So for example at 4 pm what's the visitor # for each day of week  ,today , yesterday , day before yesterday and so on . Thanks for your help taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your WHERE clause into

```
WHERE visit.pkey=action.pkey  and (visit.is_bot = 0)
AND visit.date_created >="2017-03-22 18:29:59" and visit.date_created <="2017-03-23 14:29:59"
```

**UPDATED**

- Today midnight: DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
- Today 4pm: DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))

  ```
  WHERE visit.pkey=action.pkey  and (visit.is_bot = 0)
  AND visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))
  ```

**Update 2:**
Then you'll have to expand your where clause like this I guess.

```
WHERE visit.pkey=action.pkey  and (visit.is_bot = 0)
AND (
    (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-1,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-1,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-2,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-2,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-3,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-3,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-4,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-4,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-5,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-5,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 OR (visit.date_created >= DATEADD(d,-6,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and visit.date_created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(d,-6,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))))
 )
```

Comment: I edited my question a little bit , what I want is on a specific instance like at 4:00 PM my local time I want to check everyday's data so 12:00 midnight to 4:00 PM noon I want to see everyday's data . Right now what it does is it shows today's data till 4:00 but for others it shows whole day's data

Comment: My question might not be clear 1) I am trying to retrieve 7 days result 2) I want to show data from 12 midnight to 4 PM everyday's data So for example at 4 pm what's the visitor # for each day of week ,today , yesterday , day before yesterday and so on . Thanks for your help taking time to answer my question

Comment: Does OP want a solution for SQL-Server or Mysql? The tag suggests MySql, but then again, he seems to like your SQL-Server solution too ... ;-)